# How To parse the json data in PHP

Tags: php, json

```
[    
   { "Startdate": "2016-03-07T11:00:00+00:00", "Enddate": "2016-03-11T11:00:00+00:00" },
   { "Startdate": "2016-04-11T11:30:00+00:00", "Enddate": "2016-04-15T11:30:00+00:00" },
   { "Startdate": "2016-05-07T11:30:00+00:00", "Enddate": "2016-05-21T11:30:00+00:00" },
   { "Startdate": "2016-06-18T12:00:00+00:00", "Enddate": "2016-07-02T12:00:00+00:00" },
   { "Startdate": "2016-08-20T02:00:00+00:00", "Enddate": "2016-09-03T02:00:00+00:00" },
   { "Startdate": "2016-04-16T14:30:00+00:00", "Enddate": "2016-04-23T14:30:00+00:00" },
   { "price": "₹12,500.00" },
   { "price": "₹12,500.00" },
   { "price": "₹12,500.00" },
   { "price": "₹12,500.00" },
   { "price": "₹12,500.00" },
   { "price": "₹8,100.00"  }
]
```

I want Output like this

```
Startdate : 2016-06-18T12:00:00+00:00, Enddate : 2016-09-03T02:00:00+00:00 Price :\u20b912,500.00

Startdate : 2016-06-17T12:00:00+00:00, Enddate : 2016-09-03T02:00:00+00:00 Price :\u20b912,500.00
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not a conding service. You should provide the code you have written so far and describe what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

To parse json data in php, use `json_decode`. What you have is not a valid json however. Once you parse, you can iterate using a `foreach`.